# SQL query to select results based on dynamic inputs

Tags: oracle11g

In my Project, we are using a table which has around 60 columns in it. Right now, we are showing only 12 column fields values in the results screen when the user searches with an INVOICE_NUMBER. But now the user wants the flexibility that along with those 12 column field values, he should be able to select some extra column field values for a particular INVOICE_NUMBER.
for example:
there are 5 columns(A,B,C,D,E) in a table MyTable. We are showing the result based on the query::select A,B from MyTable where C='some value'
But as per the user requirement, the query should be written in a way that he can be able to put in any of the remaining column names(D,E) and get the result accordingly. suppose he selects D column to be shown along with A and B for a particular value of C.

Can someone help with the query if it is at all possible in SQL.

Regards